# How To Open A New User Control On Selecting An Item in ListBox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listboxitem

I am a newbie in MVVM. I have a main project "MVVM Demo" which includes mainwindow.xaml file, which has my Main UI. I have a list box which has set of items:

```
<ListBox Name="ButtonPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding BoardTabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Connect}"  >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding I2C}"  >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Voltage}" >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Clock}" >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Codec}" >
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EEPROM}" >
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I need each item of listbox to open a new User Control respectively. Mind you I have created a separate User Controls outside the Main Project (a second project in my Solution file) and added it as a reference to Main Project(Board control mvvm)

Voltage is one of the userControl which has a voltage.xaml file where my Ui resides which has a separate view, model and view model class. It shud pop up  as a new window the moment i click the voltage item(text block inside the listbox) in my MainWindow.xaml which resides in Board Control MVVM project.

here is my ProductView Model Class which selects the tab from the mainwindow.xaml UI:

```
private Product m_SelectedTab;
    public Product SelectedTab
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedTab;
        }

        set
        {
            m_SelectedTab = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
        }
    }
```

I want to know when I select the item in Listbox(mainwindow.xaml), a window shud pop up with a voltage.xaml UI which is above. If u need any further code for clear description, i would love to upload here.

PLEASE HELP :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear; if Connect, I2C, Voltage etc. are the items you want in your ListBox then the above Xaml does not what you want. As each item will have all of those TextBlocks (since you define the ItemTemplate to be several TextBlocks).

Instead what I'm assuming you want is that each of those items (Connect, I2C etc.) are the items of your ListBox. Again assuming the only thing you want to do is open another page then you can use a HyperlinkButton inside each ListBoxItem:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                        
                    <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Page}">
                        <HyperlinkButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </HyperlinkButton.Style>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />                            
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here Name and Page are properties of an Item class which represents each of your items (Connect, I2C etc.) with Name being the Name (Voltage) and Page being a Uri which points to the corresponding page you want to open (/Voltage.xaml)

The ItemsSource of the ListBox is bound to an Items property of a ViewModel class with Items being an ObservableCollection of Item objects:

```
ItemsViewModel viewModel = new ItemsViewModel() {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { 
            new Item() { Name = "Item 1", Page = new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative) },
            new Item() { Name = "Item 2", Page = new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative) }}
        };
```

Note that in case you want to pass extra data to the Page you could do that via the Query string (/Voltage.xaml?param=blah) or you can add a Command to each Item and handle the navigation yourself.